# Cross compilation with Buildroot

Tags: embedded-linux, cross-compiling, buildroot

Advice on working with Buildroot cross compilation would be helpful.

I am currently using customer specific buildroot and trying to cross compile our applications using the provided toolchain. The toolchain provided by customer is in dir `[...]/opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin`. The toolchain from buildroot is in `buildroot/output/host/usr/bin`.

Previously I have worked with Yocto Project and in yocto before using cross compilation we need to install the toolchain/sdk which is generated by `bitbake -c populate_sdk <image recipe>` and then each time we wish to use the toolchain we need to source the environment script. Do we have similar things in buildroot? Do we need to source any environment script? And also do I need to modify anything in `menuconfig`? Currently the toolchain set in `menuconfig` is "Linaro ARM 2018.05".

Can anyone please let me know how to continue with Buildroot? My end goal is to cross-compile and generate binaries using this toolchain.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to use an external toolchain for building BSP.

In the buildroot menuconfig navigate to Toolchain and use below settings -

1. Toolchain type - External Toolchain
2. Toolchain - Custom toolchain
3. Toolchain origin - Pre-installed Toolchain
4. Toolchain Path - here you can choose the path ***[...]/opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin***
   and make necessary settings for remaining toolchain settings and build.
   [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5RFV.png)